# Using Angular variable in Chartjs data attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I'm currently trying to use an angular variable within a chart.js rendition of a doughnut chart. I'm also using the bootstrap official dashboard theme that allows the use of html data attributes to pass data into the chart components. I thought this would be as simple as passing in an angular variable with the data into the html data attributes, but that's not the case.

As you can see in the console output below, the angular variable has not been evaluated at the time that the chartjs code is firing.

```
{{data}}
[{ value: 330, color: '#42a5f5', label: 'Average' }, { value: 30, color: '#1bc98e', label: 'Now' }]
```

And here's where I'm logging the passed in arguments.

```
doughnut: function (element) {
  var attrData = $.extend({}, $(element).data())
  var data     = eval(attrData.value)

  console.log(attrData.value);

  Charts._cleanAttr(attrData)

  var options = $.extend({
    responsive: true,
    animation: false,
    segmentStrokeColor: '#fff',
    segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
    percentageInnerCutout: 80,
  }, attrData)

  new Chart(element.getContext('2d')).Doughnut(data, options)
},
```

The above block is a helper function written by the Bootstrap team to use Chart.js components within html blocks using data attributes. The html is below.

The HTML that doesn't work:

```
<canvas
        class="ex-graph"
        id="powerChart"
        width="200" height="200"
        data-chart="doughnut"
        data-value="{{data}}"
        data-segment-stroke-color="#222">
      </canvas>
```

The HTML that does work:

```
<canvas
        class="ex-graph"
        width="200" height="200"
        data-chart="doughnut"
        data-value="[{ value: 330, color: '#42a5f5', label: 'Average' }, { value: 30, color: '#1bc98e', label: 'Now' }]"
        data-segment-stroke-color="#222">
      </canvas>
```

The angular variable is an exact copy of the 'data-value' attr. When inspect the element in the dev console, I can see the data that it's supposed to be using.

I've tried using timeouts, ng-init, forcing a re-draw of the carts by triggering the 'redraw.bs.charts' event that was written by the Bootstrap team, but none of it is working.

Surely someone has used these components together before. Anyone has any suggestions? I'm reaching the point of frustration since it's not even throwing any errors.

Comment: I think the issue is that angular binding is performed **after** chartjs initialization. For ui interaction of this kind you need to use directives. There are [some](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) implementations already created.

Comment: I recommend you to use the directive linked by @ieaglle to avoid problems like this one